# How to combine multiple build started Jenkins messages into one email

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, repo

I am using Jenkins, Gerrit and repo for my project. Often times I make code changes that span across git repositories (all managed through repo). When I submit a CL it triggers multiple Jenkins jobs (pre-submits, cross reference checks, linters...) which sends flurry of build started emails and finally one email with +/-verified status. Wondering if it is possible to combine all the build started emails into one (just like the final verified status email)

Comment: Sounds like more of an issue with how you have your SCM build trigger as a code change should only ever affect 1 branch of 1 repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Pipeline where only one job will be triggered as part of Gerrit trigger and the Pipeline will take care of calling all other jobs and update the Gerrit with the final message.